# Sequelize belongsToMany search/filter only returns single row

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Need help with my code. Below is the sample table and following code.

**Tables**

[image: Sample tables]

[books]
| id       | title          | description        |

[categories]
| id       | name           |

[book_categories]
| id       | book_id        | category_id        |

**Association**

```
Books.belongsToMany(Categories, {
  as: 'categories',
  through: 'BookCategories',
  foreignKey: 'book_id',
  otherKey: 'category_id'
});
```

**Query**

```
const books = await Books.findAll({
  limit: 10,
  offset: offset,
  order: [
    ['id', 'DESC']
  ],
  where: {},
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'title',
    'description'
  ],
  distinct: true,
  include: [{
    model: Categories,
    as: 'categories',
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'name'
    ],
    through: {
      attributes: []
    },
    where: {
      id: data.category_id
    }
  }]
});
```

---

```sql
SELECT "Books".*,
       "categories"."id" AS "categories.id",
       "categories"."name" AS "categories.name"
FROM
  (SELECT "Books"."id",
          "Books"."title",
          "Books"."description"
   FROM "books" AS "Books"
   WHERE
       (SELECT "BookCategories"."book_id"
        FROM "book_categories" AS "BookCategories"
        INNER JOIN "categories" AS "Categories" ON "BookCategories"."category_id" = "Categories"."id"
        AND "Categories"."id" = 3
        WHERE ("Books"."id" = "BookCategories"."book_id")
        LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY "Books"."id" DESC
   LIMIT 10
   OFFSET 0) AS "Books"
INNER JOIN ("book_categories" AS "categories->BookCategories"
            INNER JOIN "categories" AS "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "categories->BookCategories"."category_id") ON "Books"."id" = "categories->BookCategories"."book_id"
AND "categories"."id" = 3
ORDER BY "Books"."id" DESC;
```

**Input**

> category_id = 3

**Output**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Book 1",
  "description": "some description 1",
  "categories": [
      {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Suspense"
      }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately this is not what I want.

**What I want**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Book 1",
  "description": "some description 1",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Adventure"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Romance"
    }
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Suspense"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing in the query?

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL query(ies)?

Comment: @Anatoly Sorry for the late reply. I've added the raw query from the logs base on the code I did.

Comment: I formatted your SQL query. Please use https://sqlformat.org next time to format SQL to be more readable

Comment: Did you try to indicate `subQuery: false` in the main query options (where `limit` and `offset` are)?

Comment: @Anatoly Thank you very much for the SQL format. I've tried `subQuery: false`, still the same results.

Comment: The exact same SQL or a little bit different?

Comment: @Anatoly its a little different when `subQuery: false` is added.

Comment: Show SQL then for `subQuery: false`. Usually `belongsToMany works through separate queries. It's just that you either use a condition on other end of many-to-many association or use `limit` and `offset`